# SQl join on date range

Tags: mysql, date, join, date-range

I have a table

```
ID, Start Date, End Date
```

I have a second table which has one column, dates from 2000 to 2050. It is a key to join start and end date on
Date_ID

I would like to take a table starting like this

```
ID, Start Date, End Date
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017
```

Then join it onto the Date Table (second table) to output a table like this

```
ID, Start Date, End Date, Day Date
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017, 1/1/2017
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017, 1/2/2017
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017, 1/3/2017
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017, 1/4/2017
123, 1/1/2017,  1/5/2017, 1/5/2017
```

I thought of joining on a date range but that does not work. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated! I am using MYSQL.

```
SELECT 
    name,
    date(start_date),
    date(end_date),
    d.id as Day_Date
FROM
    f_table1 a
Left Join
    d_table2 d on d.id = d.id between date(a.start_date) and date(a.end_date)
```

The above code of course does not run, but this is my best stab thus far.

Comment: Not sure what is your table2.  Show us sample data for both tables and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    name,
    date(start_date),
    date(end_date),
    d.id as Day_Date
FROM       f_table1 a
Left Join  d_table2 d 
    on a.id = d.id 
   and d.`Day Date` between date(a.start_date) and date(a.end_date)
```

Comment: Can this be explained in further detail? You're joining id on itself AND if it's between the start and end dates. Why does this work?

Comment: @Ritz735 That was a typo from original question I just copy and paste. From the OP the only problem was he was missing the AND for the ON clause. So I really didn't need to understand the problem because it was just solving a typo. If you have a similar problem try asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    date(start_date),
    date(end_date),
    d.id as Day_Date
FROM
    f_table1 a
RIGHT JOIN
    d_table2 d on d.id between date(a.start_date) and date(a.end_date)
```